# Extrema of the Ratio of Consecutive Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

Let $p_i$ denote the $i$th prime number. We know that $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore, if we pick some real number $c>1$, there should be some positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}<c$ for all $n>N$. Do we know anything about these values of $N$ for different values of $c$? For example, if we let $c=\frac{3}{2}$, do we know the positive integer $N$ (or an estimate) such that $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}<c$ for all $n>N$. We could ask a similar question for other values of $c$ such as $\sqrt{2}$ or $\frac{5}{3}$. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This question (or rather, an equivalent one) is the subject of [my paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2785) with V. Shevelev and P. Moses. One of the more useful tools is the [2010 paper of Dusart](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442) which uses a large verification of zeta zeros to get numerical bounds on many prime-related functions. In particular he shows that:

- For $x\ge396738,$ the interval $[x,x+x/(25\log^2x)]$ contains at least one prime.
- The $n$-th prime is at least $n\left(\log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n-2.1}{\log n}\right)$ for $n\ge3$.
- The $n$-th prime is at most $n\left(\log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n-2}{\log n}\right)$ for $n\ge688383$.

So if $n\ge688383$ then the gap between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ is at most
$$
\frac{n\left(\log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n-2}{\log n}\right)}{25\log^2\left(n\left(\log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n-2}{\log n}\right)\right)}
$$

and hence $p_{n+1}/p_n-1$ is at most
$$
f(n)=\frac{\log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n-2}{\log n}}{25\left(\log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n-2.1}{\log n}\right)\log^2\left(n\left(\log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n-2}{\log n}\right)\right)}
$$

which you can evaluate numerically.

---

As an example, $f(688383)\approx0.0001533<0.0001534$ and so if $n\ge688383$ then $p_{n+1}/p_n<1.0001534.$ Checking the primes below that point you can actually improve this to $n>49414$ which is sharp since $p_{49415}/p_{49414}=1+98/604073\approx1.0001622.$

Comment: Of course there are simpler versions you can use, at the cost of being less precise.